# Can I choose how many bots are on each team in DotA 2?

Tags: dota-2

The only way I know to play with bots is to check the "Fill empty slots with bots", or use the new "Practice Match vs Bots" option.  Can I play a game with say only 1 bot on my team, versus only 3 bots on their team?  If yes, how do I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a practice lobby with "Fill empty slots with bots" disabled. On the lobby screen, you can click on the red arrow to the right of any player slot to add a bot player of any difficulty. By adding bots this way, you can even mix and match bots of varying difficulty levels. See the picture below for reference.

[image: Dota 2 Lobby Screen]

Comment: Perfect!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I have no idea how I've missed it so far.

Comment: how to do it without an internet connection?